# bash completion with arguments containing spaces

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

How to create a bash completion script that contains spaces in the argument, the following work nicely as long as the args are space separated, but I couldn't 
make it work with args that contain spaces and are separated by a new line or the like

```
_api(){
...
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$args"  -- "$cur" ) )
...
}
complete -F _api ./command
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
_api(){
...
local IFS=$'\n'
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$args"  -- "$cur" ) )
...
}
complete -F _api ./command
```